# How to export sql tables to openoffice spreadsheet using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created c# windows application to export database table values to ms excel. How can i write code to export database table values to openoffice spreadsheet?

Comment: Do u mean from data grid view to Openoffice Spreadsheet. @karthi

Comment: No. using select query get data from table and add to spreadsheet row. I am using system.io to save document

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih send full code